# How to verify manufacturer of a smart card?

Tags: smartcard, javacard

Suppose that I want to buy a large amount of smart cards from an untrusted smart card seller. The seller claims that the chips of the smart cards are manufactured by Samsung or NXP companies. Unfortunately, because of U.S. santions, I can't communnicate with the manufacturer to verify authority of the seller or validity of its claim.

Is there any **technical approach** to check the card's manufacturer?

Comment: Please ask questions on Specific programming problems
Software algorithms
Coding techniques
Software development. Kindly use https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ to get answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

No. There are ways of identifying the chip in Global Platform, but I don't think there is any standardized way to *authenticate* the chips. That means that you can get information about the chips, but a cloned chip could simply copy that information as well. So if there is such a thing possible, it would be proprietary, e.g. hidden in a initialization part of the chip.

That brings up another issue: if the initialization key (usually a symmetric key) is known to the seller then they could use that to mess with the parameters of an original chip. How much damage can be done that way depends on the chip, but I'd at least assume that it would be possible to track chips according to the set characteristics. Detecting those kind of changes would be tricky.

Basically, just as with many parts within cryptography, to be secure you need a secure system. A untrusted smart card seller should not be part of such a system.

Comment: Of course you can make special arrangements with the chip manufacturer, but I guess that's kind of a chicken / egg problem in this particular case.